# A string interpolation within concatenation is producing two double quotes instead of one (JuliaLang)

Tags: string, julia, double-quotes

I am trying to include a single double quote in a string during a concatenation within JuliaLang, as below:

```
tmpStr = string(tmpStr, string("graph [label=\"  hi \"]; "))
```

The output in the text file written with `writedlm` is:

```
 graph [label=""  hi ""]
```

How can I modify the string interpolation to include only a single double quote instead of this repetition?

Comment: This question is hard to understand. First, you don't appear to be doing string interpolation. In Julia that would be something like `a=1;b="$a"`.  Second, you don't define `tmpStr`, or show how you are writing your output, and you include the unused `yrs`. Maybe try writing your question again with code that runs on it's own when copied and pasted.

Comment: @gggg, I use 'tmpStr' in 'writedlm' and in the output file 2 dble quotes are surrounding the text 'hi' which I want surrounded by  single dble quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra double quotes come from `writedlm`. `writedlm` uses standard CSV escaping method, which surrounds special characters with double quotes, and uses `""` to represent a single double quote. This is OK, as long as you do the inverse transformation when reading the file.

A good method to trace such problems is to create a minimal working example. In this case, something like:

```
writedlm("tst.tst",["\""])
```

Which writes `tst.tst`, but `tst.tst` now has:

```
""""
```

But when read properly:

```
julia> data = readdlm("tst.tst")
1×1 Array{Any,2}:
 "\""
```

As expected.

Another option to avoid getting the extra quotes is to add `quotes=false` as an option to `writedlm`, as in the following example:

```
julia> writedlm(STDOUT,["\""],quotes=false)
"
```